# Is it possible or a good idea to run a more or less secure minecraft server without having pre-experience in Ubuntu?

Tags: server, security, minecraft, setup

Hello Dear Ubuntu Questions Community,

This is my first on this site and is very important to me! I currently run a Minecraft Server that runs on a server that I have to move aways from, and that in the next few days, because of many different reasons! Now I planned to host the server on a Linux based machine in a datacenter! The Problem I currently have is, that I am a newbie regarding Ubuntu servers! Now my greatest concern is security: how much can go wrong, is it likey? And what could happen?

What I would require:
An Ubuntu server that ONLY (at first) hosts the Minecraft Server!
That is the minimum! Everything else can be done later. Also good would be a MySQL Server for the databaseses... (but expandable)

Later on, a LAMP server would be nice, but that is, as said, no current necessity!

Now, how unsecure could that be? What would I have to do, other then installing Java and starting the server on the server?...

Or does anyone know a step-by-step guide?...

Please give me an answer regarding that topic, I would be really glad!

Thank you very much in advance!

PS: PLEASE Don't give me a standard "don't touch servers as a noob" post... I got enough of those... I need facts, that I can orientate with!!

Comment: Welcome to AU!  It is helpful to ask [specific](http://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask) questions, focusing on one question per post.  Reading your post, I'm not sure what is the main question you want us to help you answer.  You do mention security, which [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/856/6161) question covers.  You also mention looking for a step-by-step guide - do you want a guide for setting up [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Servers) or for setting up Minecraft?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to ask Ubuntu! Just as a comment, I think that your question is confusing. You might want to consider being a bit more specific as to what you want. I can't tell if you are asking if Ubuntu server is secure, or how it runs, or how to get a Minecraft server running, or what people recommend for such a server, or if any one knows of a guide,etc. You will get more answers to your questions if they are short and direct :)

Now I have no experience with servers, but I found what seems to look like a tutorial as to how to setup a Minecraft Server with Ubuntu. I'm sure you have the experience to understand it: https://github.com/endofzero/Minecraft-Sheller

I found this link in someone else question on Ask Ubuntu. Maybe you could try messaging those users about setting up a Minecraft Server, they seem very experienced: [Interact with Minecraft Server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48251/interact-with-minecraft-server)

---

I see what you mean now :) I assume trying to setup a Ubuntu server for the first time will lead to some begginer mistakes. But that's how you learn, trying! Maybe start with the basics. Here is the official Ubuntu server guide https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/index.html It starts with the very basics, leading up to more advanced task. I suggest you setup a test server to toy around with, that way no damage can be caused. So make some coffee, sit back and enjoy a good read of the guide:p

Comment: Hello again and first of all thank you very much for the fast replies! I know, my post might be a little confusing! Now to clarify it: I plan to setup an ubuntu server! The problem is: I am not experienced! I want to "put" my, already existing Minecraft Server application and its files on it! Now my Problem is that I am not experienced with Ubuntu Servers and am scared of doing something wrong that could get me in trouble! Now my question is if it was a good idea to try and to set one up, or are the dangers too high? And yes, a guide to set up an Ubuntu server (fast) would be awesome! :)

Comment: I see what you mean now :) I assume trying to setup a Ubuntu server for the first time will lead to some begginer mistakes. But that's how you learn, trying! Maybe start with the basics. Here is the official Ubuntu server guide https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/index.html It starts with the very basics, leading up to more advanced task. I suggest you setup a test server to toy around with, that way no damage can be caused. So make some coffee, sit back and enjoy a good read of the guide:p