# How to set up a secure Ubuntu Server running a Minecraft Bukkit Server and MySQL as a newbie?

Tags: minecraft, setup

Dear Ubuntu Community,

[my last post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133984/is-it-possible-or-a-good-idea-to-run-a-more-or-less-secure-minecraft-server-with/133999#133999) seemed to be too confusing, so I decided to ask my question again!

As the title suggests, I am pretty new to Ubuntu Server and have only used the Ubuntu Desktop version so far, and even not very extensively!
My question is, what steps are there to be taken by me, to set up an ubuntu server with standard security, running a Minecraft Bukkit Server. Are there any specific extra steps that I would have to perform, other then the ones of a normal setup? And when it comes to the "normal setup", is there any "short" guide? Because I currently do not have month to learn myself into the topic but atmost weeks... The faster the better! I know, not a very good approach, but it is very important to me, because my current server community needs a new server!

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This Is exactly what I did for my server, all you need to do is install java and id add a whitelist for your ssh server so you can prevent brute forcing attacks which are heavy on your servers resources. And also I found when I started my server with putty or any other ssh session, the server would stop as soon as I closed out putty. So I learned how to start it and keep it running 24/7.

Screen -S minecraft java -Xincgc Xmx1G -jar minecraft_server.jar
To exit out of the screen do
Crtl + a then do Crtl + d
And to get to the screen after exiting do
screen -rx

Hope this helps you, any other questions email me :)

Comment: You may want to edit this answer. Currently, its formatting is seriously broken. It's not entirely clear to me what commands you are recommend people run.